# Change default archive decompression action for archives

Tags: files, 16.10, default, archive

It seems that the newly deployed files (3.22.2 at least) decompresses archives automatically and by default, with no obvious way of regressing it to an archive explorer. Does anyone know how to change this default action?

It is REALLY annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, should have looked deeper before asking. It can be changed under Preferences > Behaviour.

I'll let this up for anyone who made the same lazy mistake.